# How to generate duplicate items in a list using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

this is LINQ  query I have used

```
var result = (from price in inventoryDb.Pricing.AsNoTracking()               
              where price.Quantity > 0m
              select new
              {
                 TagNo = price.TagNo,
                 SellingRate = price.SellingRate,
                 Quantity = price.Quantity           
              }).ToList();
```

Based on the `Quantity` value I need to generate duplicate items in the list.

**Output :**

```
result = [0]{TagNo="100", SellingRate=1500.00, Quantity=1}
         [1]{TagNo="101", SellingRate=1600.00, Quantity=2}
```

**Expected Result:**

```
result = [0]{TagNo="100", SellingRate=1500.00}
         [1]{TagNo="101", SellingRate=1600.00}
         [2]{TagNo="101", SellingRate=1600.00}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.SelectMany` + `Enumerable.Range`:

```
var result = inventoryDb.Pricing.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(p => p.Quantity > 0m)
    .SelectMany(p => Enumerable.Range(0, p.Quantity)
        .Select(i => new
              {
                 TagNo = p.TagNo,
                 SellingRate = p.SellingRate      
              }))
    .ToList();
```

If that's not supported by your LINQ provider (f.e. `Linq-To-Entities`), the easiest is to use `Linq-To-Objects`. To avoid that all is loaded into memory you should use `AsEnumerable` after the `Where`:

```
var result = inventoryDb.Pricing.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(p => p.Quantity > 0m)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .SelectMany(p => Enumerable.Range(0, p.Quantity)
        .Select(i => new
              {
                 TagNo = p.TagNo,
                 SellingRate = p.SellingRate      
              }))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

Keeping with the query syntax just add a `Enumerable.Repeat` as follows:

```
var result = (from price in inventoryDb.Pricing.AsNoTracking()
              where price.Quantity > 0m
              from dup in Enumerable.Repeat(0,price.Quantity)
              select new
              {
                 TagNo = price.TagNo,
                 SellingRate = price.SellingRate,          
              }).ToList();
```

If indeed linq to entities does not support then add `AsEnumerable` like follows:

```
var result = (from price in inventoryDb.Pricing.AsNoTracking()
                                               .Where(p => p.Quantity > 0m)
                                               .AsEnumerable() //Loads only the filtered items to memory            
              from dup in Enumerable.Repeat(0,price.Quantity)
              select new
              {
                 TagNo = price.TagNo,
                 SellingRate = price.SellingRate,          
              }).ToList();
```

*You can also use `Enumerable.Range` but because you do not use the value of that collection (and in my opinion also just that it describes better what you are doing) I decided just to go with `Repeat`*

Comment: That's the obvious LINQ To Objects solution. The question is though would this work at all with the EF (notice `inventoryDb.Pricing.AsNoTracking()`). I'll put my bet on `NotSupportedException` :)

Comment: @IvanStoev, Just add `.AsEnumerable()` before calling `Enumerable.Repeat`.

Comment: @IvanStoev - Thanks for noticing :) you are correct and I forgot to check that. See update

Comment: @kiziu - Thanks for the suggestion