# Adding an object to an existing list during iteration

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, c#-4.0

I have a list which consists of 5 objects.

```
List<ObjA> listA = new List<ObjA>();
```

I have a requirement where while iterating through the list , if some condition is met I need to create a copy of the current object and modify one property and add it back to the listA.
I can create a separate list and after the for loop, I can add it to listA but is there any better way to achieve this?

```
foreach(var a in listA)
{
  //if(a.somecondition is true)
  // create a clone of 'a' and add it to listA
}
```

Comment: Create a copy of the original list; iterate through one version and populate the other.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate duplicate items in a list using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39914274/how-to-generate-duplicate-items-in-a-list-using-linq)

Comment: What is wrong with creating a separate list and adding them all afterwards? It would probably be the most readable code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a list, you can iterate by index:

```
// save the length before we iterate so that we don't iterate into new items
int length = listA.Count; 

// loop from 0 to the original length
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
{
    var a = listA[i];
    if (a.somecondition)
    {
        listA.Add(YourCloneMethod(a));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't modify a list while it iterates you can make a copy before you iterate:

```
foreach(var a in listA.ToList())
{
  //if(a.somecondition is true)
  // create a clone of 'a' and add it to listA
  var copyOfA = /* make copy of a */.
  listA.Add(copyOfA);
}
```

Comment: And if this was a massive list, it would be horribly inefficient. If one of my devs submitted this in a PR, I'd go tell them to rewrite it.

Comment: This would also copy the cloned object values for all the original objects in the list

Comment: You are completely right @DavidG I don't see anything about the size of the list here. Please post your solution since you seem to be so proficient :)

Comment: @VA1267 What do you mean by your comment?

Comment: @VA1267 No because classes are handled by reference and not by value in C#. If you are dealing with structs this is of course not a good solution.

Comment: @RedX I don't need to post a solution, the one above by Llama is sufficient, but my comment on the question is also relevant

Answer (score 1):

I think creating new list and copy object there would be simpler to follow approach.

```
var newList = oldList.SelectMany(item =>
{
    if (someCondition) 
    {
        var updatedClone = // create clone
        return new[] { item, updatedClone };
    }
    return new[] { item };      
}).ToList();
```

You can remove creation of extra arrays by introducing extension method

```
public static IEnumerable<Item> TryAddUpdatedClone(this Item item)
{
    yield return item;
    if (someCondition)
    {
        var updatedClone = // create clone with new values
        yield return updatedClone;
    }
}

// Usage
var newList = oldList.SelectMany(item => item.TryAddUpdatedClone()).ToList();
```